# android - FloatingActionButton Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

I want to use Floating Action Button in my application ,to do so I got the latest support library 22.2.1 and add the it to my application as a library. I cleaned the project and there was no more errors . 
Then I put this code in my xml layout , but when I run my application ,I ran into an error that I couldn't solve it .

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is no the whole code ,I've some other views in the linearlayout and at the end i put FloatingActionButton.

When I run my application ,I get this error :

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.karaj.project/com.karaj.project.FistActiivty}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #301: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #301: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.karaj.project.DrawerActivity.setContentView(DrawerActivity.java:73)
    at com.karaj.project.FistActiivty.onCreate(FistActiivty.java:88)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.karaj.persiandesigners-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.karaj.persiandesigners-1, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    ... 20 more
```

What am I doing wrong ?
thanks

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton", did you include the support library in Gradle?

Comment: You have to use design library provided by android.

Answer (score 10):

Do not add support library as jar file to your project
add this line to the gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

and update the android support "REPOSITORY"

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, thanks.  However, I should point out that more recent versions of Android produce "WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.  It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html", and require `implementation: 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` instead.

Answer (score -3):

Add dependencies in your project using

compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'

and after that sync project

Comment: The question is not about [makovkastar's FloatingActionBar](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton). It is about the default one in the android design support library. The answer has nothing to do with the issue described in the question.